# Two questions regarding WCF REST service structure

Tags: wcf, rest

I have two questions I hope I can get an answer for with regard to my service oriented application

1. I am creating a service oriented application where controls have no events, it's all done by calling services... that means the service url is written in my jQuery code, but this seems somehow not nice.... It's like what is the best option to save service urls?! I feel it's hard to maintain and not secure when it's written inside the page or inside javascript referenced file.
2. I am talking to a hosting company and they told me that I can host this application services on cloud server and the application on another servers.... not all in the same server, but my application services are self hosted, I mean the services are inside the application.... so to make things work as my hosting company wants, shall I host the restful services in IIS or how exactly?

Comment: Ambigous name, and I think the questions should be separate.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding in the communication with your hosting company. You have a single application that needs to be hosted. Period. Whether a request returns HTML, JSON or XML shouldn't matter to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Service URL must be in your page or script source file. It can be local address unless you are using cross domain calls and JSONP - cross domain calls requires absolute address. It is the same as any other web technology. If you want navigation to other page, you must provide URL. If you want some picture or css file you must provide URL. Security is up to you.
2. This will be the problem of cross domain calls. Normally JS calls can be done only to the same domain where the page is exposed. Once the application server is exposed on different domain name your calls will not work. To avoid that you must use JSONP (WCF 4 has support for that). Exposing rest services consumed by your application from self hosted application is strange. REST services are consumed by your clients - they are front-end services and should be part of your application hosted on front-end web server. Your back-end application server should not host anything directly accessible by your clients.

Comment: mmmm...okay but this is my architecture , the whole system is built on services there are no page events , the only thing i have in my aspx is the controls....so the pages must be a solution and the services must be running in another solution ? I hope i am understanding your answer.

Comment: No. I would make services part of your solution/project where you have your pages because your pages doesn't work without these services - it is one set of functionality exposed to clients.

Comment: mmm..but what if later , I wanted to have all those services running alone on another server to speed things up?? how would this work when they are self hosted ?

Comment: Cant i use jsonp between the pages project and the services project?

Comment: Yes it should work if you use JSONP but for me your deployment scenario seems to be overcomplicated. Services are essential part of your web application so there is no reason to break the application into two separate deployments. Moreover placing services to separate application will demand hard coding their absolute address into your pages.

Comment: they are already now hardcoded.....this is what I want to change , it's my first question in the post.

Comment: I am also afraid of session state....as I am using session state in the services , I know it seems very complicated but for some reason I feel it's going to be extremely fast.

Comment: Session state doesn't work when self hosting web services - they must be hosted in ASP.NET pipeline on the web server. Also REST services SHOULD NOT use session. The REST mean Representational state transfer - all state should be in transferred messages.

Comment: aspNetCompatibilityEnabled doesnt this attribute allows session to be used when calling the services , it's working in my application.

Comment: I just tested this myself to make it sure. If I use `aspNetCompatibilityEnabled` in configuration for self hosted REST service and mark service with `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute` where I define that service requires the compatibility I will get this exception during start: *This service requires ASP.NET compatibility and must be hosted in IIS. ...* Without compatibility `HttpContext.Current` is always null and you cannot access the ASP.NET session.

Comment: okay now I have a huge mis understanding i hope you can fix for me...this is my configuration .     <system.serviceModel>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true"  automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" >
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>

Comment: and this is the service ,   [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST",BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped , UriTemplate="StartLogin")]
        public string Login(LoginInfo logInfo)
        { } ...    is this self hosting or iis hosting ?!

Comment: Are you using self hosting or not? Do you have  .svc files for your services or `ServicRoute` defined in routing configuration?

Comment: Self hosting means that you have console application, windows service or some winforms/wpf application where you create `ServiceHost` instance and self host the service.

Comment: I do have .svc files , but I am not creating any service host or something....I am calling them from jquery using uri and http verbs.

Comment: Then you are not using self hosting - you are still using hosting in web server and because of that aspNetCompatibility works.

Comment: does this mean that I can move my services to another project and separate them from my pages project ? and really thanks for making me understand things more

Comment: it might be a dream comming true but I want to think of a solution to step using session state....as this structure have eliminated viewstate so want to complete the job.

Comment: Yes you can but you still have to remember that it can make your deployment harder and it can introduce cross domain calls. Once you move your services to separate project they become separate web application. You can deploy that application completely separately but in such case it will most probably have different domain name and address with this domain name must be part of your URLs in your script files or web pages. You can make this configurable in your web application containing web pages where you will have appSetting with the base URL and you will pass it to the page as JS variable.

Comment: By JS variable I mean custom `<script>...</script>` block created on the server.

Comment: Thanks....thanks alot , I really appreciate your help..and hopefully this hard structure can create the speed I want to.

Comment: If eliminating view state was the only reason for you to develop the application this way I have interesting news for you. You can configure ASP.NET web forms to store view state in session state automatically with out of the box features. So the view state is not send over the wire.

Comment: Yeah I know this option , i guess it's called persistviewstate or something like this...but this will send the cost to the server so It's not like removing it totally , but my idea was to create an application that takes care of every kb being transferred from client to server and vice versa .

Comment: i think sites like hotmail facebook gmail use something similar.

Comment: But in such case you should use ASP.NET MVC. That would remove all these complexities and those "services" will be part of your application directly implemented in controllers = no WCF overhead.

Comment: haha thanks I didnt know this info , I already reached 20% so next project i'll try mvc.